# Clearing NeoPixel LEDs after running animate()?

Tags: python, animation, micropython, adafruit-circuitpython, neopixel

I'm trying to run an animation for a period of time, then clear the LEDs and go back to setting the colors manually with `Neopixel.pixels.fill()`. Only, after I run `animation.animate()`, I lose the ability to use `pixels.fill()` I tried using the sequence library with the `auto_clear` and `auto_reset` flags, but those did not seem to work either.

```
rainbow = Rainbow(macropad.pixels, speed = 0.005, period = 2)
animations = AnimationSequence(rainbow, auto_clear=True, auto_reset=True)

i = 0
while True:
    animations.animate()
    i += 1
    if (i == 100):
         animations.reset()
         break
```